# Show that $E \subset \Bbb Q$ is closed in $(\Bbb Q, d)$

Tags: metric-spaces, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

> Assume $(\Bbb Q, d),$ $d(p, q):= |p -q|$
> is a metric space and
>
> $E := \{p \in \Bbb Q : 2 < p^2 < 3\} \subset \Bbb Q.$
>
> I have to show that $E$ is closed.

I see two ways of proving this statement.

**Approach 1:**

First, we note that

$$E = \{p \in \Bbb Q : 2 < p^2 < 3\} = \{p \in \Bbb Q : \sqrt2 < p < \sqrt3\}.$$

Furthermore, $E$ is closed if and only if

$$\Bbb Q \setminus E := \{p \in \Bbb Q: p \notin (\sqrt2, \sqrt3)\}$$

is open. So, assume $p \in \Bbb Q \setminus E.$ I have to show that there exists an $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that

$B_{\epsilon}(p) \subset \Bbb Q \setminus E.$

We can assume that$ p \neq \sqrt2$ since $\sqrt2$ is irrational. Let $p$ be any other point that lies close to $\sqrt2$ while $p < \sqrt2$ still holds. Then, it follows directly that there must be an $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that

$|p - \sqrt2| \lt \epsilon.$

This works the exact same way for $\sqrt3,$ and other points of $\Bbb Q \setminus E$ don't require any attention. Therefore,

$B_{\epsilon}(p) \subset \Bbb Q \setminus E$

for every $p \in \Bbb Q \setminus E.$

**Approach 2:**

We remember the following theorem: (using the given premises of course)

$E$ is closed <=> $(x_k)$ is a sequence of points $x_k \in E$ that converges to a point $x \in \Bbb Q \Rightarrow x \in E$.

This obvously holds for every $x \in E$ since $E \subset \Bbb Q.$ Now, there can't be any other points of $\Bbb Q$ a sequence $(x_k)$ converges to since the infinum and suprenum are given by $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$ (this doesn't make any sense, does it?), and neither can $(x_k)$ converge to $\sqrt2$ or $\sqrt3$ since they are irrational. So the statement would be trivially true.

Uhm, yeah, I'm really not sure about this one though. Can I really assume that the sequence doesn't converge to any other point bigger than $\sqrt3$ or smaller than $\sqrt2$? Furthermore, one could assume that a sequence (if it was a Cauchy-sequence) does indeed converge to $\sqrt2$ or $\sqrt3$ - at least this was the approach we took when proving that $\Bbb Q$ is not complete. On the other hand, following the theorem, I would have to assume that these irrational numbers are elements of $E$ then, which doesn't make any sense either.

Comment: As a general comment - in any problem that's solely about $\mathbb{Q}$, introducing $\sqrt{2}$ and such is almost certainly a mistake.  For this problem, work only in $\mathbb{Q}$ and speak only of numbers that exist there.  Temporarily adopt the mindset: "Every number can be written as the ratio of two integers.  Consequently, there is no number whose square is 2."  The word "irrational" should not be in your vocabulary.

Comment: @NateEldredge But what if $\mathbb Q$ is looked at as a subspace of $\mathbb R$? See my answer for an application that explicitly uses $\sqrt2$.

Comment: @Vera: Of course it is possible to do that, but my suggestion is that you don't.  It brings in a huge amount of "non-intrinsic" extra machinery, and exercises like this are usually intended to give the student practice in working within the rationals.

Comment: @NateEldredge Okay then. However, in my view your "almost certainly" is a bit too strong. Especially this case shows that it can also lead to a solution that avoids quite some fuzz. I would make it "quite often",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach:

Observe that the topology on $\mathbb Q$ is the same as the subspace topology on $\mathbb Q\subseteq\mathbb R$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R$ where $\mathbb R$ is equipped with its usual topology.

You can write: $$E=\mathbb Q\cap\left([-\sqrt3,-\sqrt2]\cup[\sqrt2,\sqrt3]\right)$$ Here $F:=[-\sqrt3,-\sqrt2]\cup[\sqrt2,\sqrt3]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ and consequently $E=\mathbb Q\cap F$ is closed in subspace $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Nice solution that gives another perspective on the problem. :-) What do you say about my second approach? Do you see any flaws there?

Comment: Your second approach can be practicized like this: Let  $x_k\in E\cap\mathbb Q$ s.t. $x_k\to x\in\mathbb Q$. Then $x_k^2\to x^2$ where $2\leq2< x_k^2<3\leq3$ and consequently $2\leq x^2\leq3$. Secondly $x\in\mathbb Q$ (so $x^2\notin\{2,3\}$) and the final conclusion is that $x\in E$. If you meant to say this in your approach then it is okay.